# Argument type 'A' is not assignable to type 'B'?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5

I am trying to understand why I am getting this exception when the interface I am passing in to my base constructor implements the correct interfaces.

Example interfaces:

```
public interface IAppService<T,TSpecification> where T: AppEntity 
    where TSpecification: IBaseSpecification<T>
{
......
}

//I tried setting both the ISomeEntitySpecification and SomeEntitySpecification implementation
public interface ISomeService: IAppService<SomeEntity,ISomeEntitySpecification>
{
.....
}

public interface ISomeEntitySpecification: IBaseSpecification<SomeEntity>
{
.....
}

public interface IBaseSpecification<T> where T: class
{
 ....
}
```

Example implementations:

```
public class SomeEntitySpecification: BaseSpecification<SomeEntity>, ISomeEntitySpecification
{
...
}

public class SomeService: AppService<SomeEntity,SomeEntitySpecification>, ISomeService
{
....
}
```

Example Usage:

```
public BaseAppController<T>: Controller where T: AppEntity 
{
    public BaseAppController(IAppService<T, IBaseSpecification<T>>)
    {
     .....
    }

}

//This is where i get the error
public SomeController: BaseAppController<SomeEntity>
{
      public SomeController(ISomeService someService):base(someService)
      {
      .....
      }
}
```

The IDE for visual studio is telling me that `someService` cannot be assigned to the `BaseAppController`'s constructor parameter. I am not sure why.

Comment: Does SomeEntity derive from AppEntity?

Comment: @Euphoric, yes it does.

Comment: Are you 100% sure? Because that is only cause for error you can get from that line.

Comment: Can you show the signature for `IBaseSpecification<T>`?

Comment: I am 100% positive...Otherwise, I would get errors in my service classes too. That is not happening

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to pass an instance of `ISomeService`, which derives from `IAppService<SomeEntity,ISomeEntitySpecification>`, to a constructor that expects an `IAppService<T, IBaseSpecification<T>>`.

And there's no hierarchical relationship between these two:

- `IAppService<SomeEntity,ISomeEntitySpecification>` and
- `IAppService<T, IBaseSpecification<T>>`,

because the generic type parameter is *invariant*.
 Since there's no relationship, you can't pass it as an argument to the constructor. It would be like passing an integer to a method expecting a string.

You're looking for covariance. Take a look at this: [Covariance and Contravariance FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx)

Comment: +1 for deciphering the code, I suspected a covariance issue, but couldn't unravel the interfaces to be sure!

Comment: +1 I was working on this and seeing the issue with `ISomeService` but hadn't quite reached this point.  Nice work!

Comment: @LordTakkera True, it's quite confusing. Piece of advice: I would redesign this. Using generics and several levels of abstraction is pretty cool, but that code is gonna be a living hell to maintain or understand for the next person who looks at it (which might be someone else, or maybe you in a couple of months).  [Keep it simple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

Comment: @dcastro, typically there is no need for me to pass in a specific IBaseSpecification implementation. I agree, I should refactor this a bit. I got crazy with the abstraction when I was developing this.